# PGM Receive very slow causing messages to be dropped?

Tags: zeromq, pgm-protocol

I'm looking into ZeroMQ for its PGM support.
Running on Windows (in a VirtualBox with MacOS as host, if that could matter), using the NetMQ library.

The test I want to do is very simple: send messages from A to B *as fast as possible*...

First I used TCP as transport; this got easily to >150 000 messages per second, with two receivers keeping pace.
Then I wanted to test PGM; all I did was to replace the address "tcp://*:5556" with "pgm://239.0.0.1:5557" on both sides.

Now, the PGM tests give very strange results: the sender easily gets to >200 000 messages/s; the receiver though, manages to process only about 500 messages/s !?

So, I don't understand what is happening. 
After slowing down the sender (sleep 10ms after each message, since otherwise it's practically impossible to investigate the flow) it appears to me that the receiver is trying to keep up, initially sees every message passing by, then chokes, misses a range of messages, then tries to keep up again...
I played with the HWM and Recovery Interval settings, but that didn't seem to make much difference (?!).

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Many thanks,
Frederik

Note: Not sure if it's matters: as far as I understand, I don't use OpenPGM - I just download the ZeroMQ setup, and enabled 'Multicasting Support' in Windows.

This is the Sender code:

```
class MassSender
{
    private const string TOPIC_PREFIX = "Hello:";

    private static int messageCounter = 0;
    private static int timerCounter = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;

        SendMessages_0MQ_NetMQ(timer);
    }

    private static void SendMessages_0MQ_NetMQ(Timer timer)
    {
        using (NetMQContext context = NetMQContext.Create())
        {
            using (NetMQSocket publisher = context.CreateSocket(ZmqSocketType.Pub))
            {
                //publisher.Bind("tcp://*:5556");
                publisher.Bind("pgm://239.0.0.1:5557"); // IP of interface is not specified so use default interface.

                timer.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    string message = GetMessage();

                    byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    publisher.Send(body);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetMessage()
    {
        return TOPIC_PREFIX + "Message " + (++messageCounter).ToString();
    }
    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=== SENT {0} MESSAGES SO FAR - TOTAL AVERAGE IS {1}/s ===", messageCounter, messageCounter / ++timerCounter);
    }
}
```

and the Receiver:

```
class MassReceiver
{
    private const string TOPIC_PREFIX = "Hello:";

    private static int messageCounter = 0;
    private static int timerCounter = 0;
    private static string lastMessage = String.Empty;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Assume that sender and receiver are started simultaneously.
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;

        ReceiveMessages_0MQ_NetMQ(timer);
    }

    private static void ReceiveMessages_0MQ_NetMQ(Timer timer)
    {
        using (NetMQContext context = NetMQContext.Create())
        {
            using (NetMQSocket subscriber = context.CreateSocket(ZmqSocketType.Sub))
            {
                subscriber.Subscribe(""); // Subscribe to everything

                //subscriber.Connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
                subscriber.Connect("pgm://239.0.0.1:5557"); // IP of interface is not specified so use default interface.

                timer.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    messageCounter++;

                    byte[] body = subscriber.Receive();

                    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);                        
                    lastMessage = message; // Only show message when timer elapses, otherwise throughput drops dramatically.  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=== RECEIVED {0} MESSAGES SO FAR - TOTAL AVERAGE IS {1}/s === (Last: {2})", messageCounter, messageCounter / ++timerCounter, lastMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the size of each message?

You are not using OpenPGM, you are using what is called ms-pgm  (Microsoft implementation of PGM).

Anyway you might have to change the MulticastRate of the socket (it defaults to 100kbit/s).

Also what kind of network are you using?

Comment: Messages are very very small, just "Hello:Message 1234"  
  
Do you think ms-pgm is worse than OpenPGM?

Comment: Messages are very very small, just "Hello:Message 1234". Do you think ms-pgm is worse than OpenPGM? I'll try playing with MulticastRate - I guess you mean to increase it on Receiver side? Regarding network: so far both sender and receiver are in the same VM (VirtualBox on MacOS host)... I understand from other posts that using 'loopback' may cause issues, could this be the case here? (note that traffic over tcp is no issue)...
Many thanks!

Comment: You should change it on the sender side.

Comment: Multicast loopback on virtual machine may be the reason but I'm pretty sure the problem is with the multicast rate. Let's say your message size is 20B, the default rate is 100Kbits/s, which is 640 messages of 20B.

Comment: tnx, marked your response as answer since indeed, MulticastRate helps to get >150 000 msgs/s with PGM. *However*... now from time to time the Receiver gets a NullReferenceException from time to time out of NetMQ.dll. I'll post a separate question about that.

Comment: Instead of posting here, I created a new issue on Github: https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, the sender can send thousands of messages per second. But my receiver can only receive two hundred messages per second.

I think it could be sending or receiving rate is limited. I check

**`ZMQ_RATE:`** Set multicast data rate in http://api.zeromq.org/3-0:zmq-setsockopt

[image: The document screenshot]

The default rate is just 100kb/s.

When I increase it to 1Gb/s, everything is OK now.

```
const int rate = 1000000;                              // 1Gb TX- and RX- rate
m_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_RATE, &rate, sizeof(rate));
```